# Is there any NAS device with wireless router capability?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, nas

Some thing along the line of Apple Time Capsule but with hard drive extension bay(s) and capable of running linux/freenas ?

Comment: I don't think this question counts as a shopping recommendation, but there are people voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

Any Linux-based router running [TomatoUSB](http://tomatousb.org/) along with an external HDD would have those abilities.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best would be a [LaCiE Wireless Space](http://www.lacie.com/uk/products/product.htm?id=10520).  It has routing abilities (ethernet only), WiFi, a hard drive, USB ports for extra disks / flash, and all in one sleek box.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any of-the-shelf solutions, so my advice would be to buy (or build) the NAS along with a wireless access point. Then connect the two directly with an Ethernet cable.

Although it's possible to build a NAS with an integrated wireless card (for example, some mini-ITX motherboards include a wireless PCI Express Mini card), it would be difficult to guarantee driver support - especially with FreeNAS.